# exposing AVAudioSession in QBVideoChat

Tags: ios, video, chat, quickblox

Are there any plans to expose the existing AVAudioSession in QBVideoChat?  I realize there's a way to create your own and hand off individual frames to QBVideoChat but in some cases it would be cleaner to operate on the existing session and not have to create and handle individual frames.  I'm thinking of a case where you may want to add a custom AVCaptureOutput to the session for recording or special processing.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways now how to incorporate iOS VideoChat:

1) Use master branch https://github.com/QuickBlox/Sample-VideoChat-ios

In this case everything is under hood, you don't work direct with AVAudioSession, SDK does all this for you

2) Use customCaptureSession brunch https://github.com/QuickBlox/Sample-VideoChat-ios/tree/customCaptureSession

In this case you can use own  AVAudioSession instead of one inside SDK and control all video things.

This is up to you what to choose

Comment: Thanks.  So I guess the answer is no.  I'm currently using the second approach.